# How reach peak flops

Tags: go, parallel-processing, vectorization, gccgo

I'm an experienced C++ programmer, used to low level optimization an I'm trying to get performances out of Go.

So far, I'm interested in GFlop/s.

I wrote the following go code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "runtime"
        "sync"
)


func expm1(x float64) float64 {
        return ((((((((((((((15.0 + x) * x + 210.0) * x + 2730.0) * x + 32760.0) * x + 360360.0) * x + 3603600.0) * x + 32432400.0) * x + 259459200.0) * x + 1816214400.0) * x + 10897286400.0) * x + 54486432000.0) * x + 217945728000.0) *
x + 653837184000.0) * x + 1307674368000.0) * x * 7.6471637318198164759011319857881e-13;
}

func twelve(x float64) float64 {
        return expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1( expm1(x))))))))))));
}

func populate(data []float64, N int) {
        CPUCOUNT := runtime.NumCPU();
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        var slice = N / CPUCOUNT;
        wg.Add(CPUCOUNT)
        defer wg.Wait()

        for i := 0; i < CPUCOUNT; i++ {
                go func(ii int) {
                        for j := ii * slice; j < ii * slice + slice; j += 1 {
                                data[j] = 0.1;
                        }
                        defer wg.Done();
                }(i);
        }
}

func apply(data []float64, N int) {
        CPUCOUNT := runtime.NumCPU();
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        var slice = N / CPUCOUNT;
        wg.Add(CPUCOUNT)
        defer wg.Wait()

        for i := 0; i < CPUCOUNT; i++ {
                go func(ii int) {
                        for j := ii * slice; j < ii * slice + slice; j += 8 {
                                data[j] = twelve(data[j]);
                                data[j+1] = twelve(data[j+1]);
                                data[j+2] = twelve(data[j+2]);
                                data[j+3] = twelve(data[j+3]);
                                data[j+4] = twelve(data[j+4]);
                                data[j+5] = twelve(data[j+5]);
                                data[j+6] = twelve(data[j+6]);
                                data[j+7] = twelve(data[j+7]);
                        }
                        defer wg.Done();
                }(i);
        }
}

func Run(data []float64, N int) {
        populate(data, N);
        start:= time.Now();
        apply(data, N);
        stop:= time.Now();
        elapsed:=stop.Sub(start);
        seconds := float64(elapsed.Milliseconds()) / 1000.0;
        Gflop := float64(N) * 12.0 * 15.0E-9;
        fmt.Printf("%f\n", Gflop / seconds);
}

func main() {
        CPUCOUNT := runtime.NumCPU();
        fmt.Printf("num procs : %d\n", CPUCOUNT);
        N := 1024*1024*32 * CPUCOUNT;
        data:= make([]float64, N);
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
                Run(data, N);
        }
}
```

which is an attempt of translation from my c++ benchmark which yields 80% of peak flops.

The C++ version yields 95 GFlop/s where the go version yields 6 GFlops/s (FMA counter for 1).

Here is a piece of the go assembly (gccgo -O3 -mfma -mavx2):

```
vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm15, %xmm0
        .loc 1 12 50
        vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm14, %xmm0
        .loc 1 12 64
        vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm13, %xmm0
        .loc 1 12 79
        vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm12, %xmm0
        .loc 1 12 95
        vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm11, %xmm0
        .loc 1 12 112
        vfmadd132sd     %xmm1, %xmm10, %xmm0
```

And what I get from my c++ code (g++ -fopenmp -mfma -mavx2 -O3):

```
vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm12, %ymm5
        vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm11, %ymm4
        vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm10, %ymm3
        vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm9, %ymm2
        vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm8, %ymm1
        vfmadd213pd     .LC3(%rip), %ymm15, %ymm0
        vfmadd213pd     .LC4(%rip), %ymm15, %ymm0
        vfmadd213pd     .LC4(%rip), %ymm14, %ymm7
        vfmadd213pd     .LC4(%rip), %ymm13, %ymm6
        vfmadd213pd     .LC4(%rip), %ymm12, %ymm5
        vfmadd213pd     .LC4(%rip), %ymm11, %ymm4
```

I therefore have a few questions, most important of which is :

- *Do I express parallelism the right way ?*

and if not, how should I do that ?

For additional performance improvements, I'd need to know what's wrong with the following items :

- Why do I see only vfmadd132sd instructions in the assembly, instead of vfmadd132pd?
- How can I properly align memory allocations?
- How can I remove debug info from the generated executable?
- Do I pass the right options to gccgo?
- Do I use the right compiler?

Comment: Note that [goroutines](https://blog.golang.org/waza-talk) provide [concurrency, not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/waza-talk)

Comment: You've asked far too many questions at once. Can you narrow it to one at a time?

Comment: @flimzy narrowed to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i express parallelism the right way ?

No. You might be trashing the CPU cache. (But this is hard to tell without knowing details about your system. Guess it's not NUMA?). Anyway, technically your code is concurrent not parallel.

> Why do I see only vfmadd132sd instructions in the assembly, instead of vfmadd132pd ?

Because the compiler put it there. Is this a compiler question or a programming  question?

> How can i properly align memory allocations ?

That depends on your definition of "properly". Struct field and slice alignments are not ad hoc controllable, but you can reorder struct fields (which you did  not use at all, so I do not know what you are asking here).

> How can i remove debug info from the generated executable ?

Consult the documentation of gcc.

> Do i pass the right options to gccgo ?

I do not know.

> Do I use the right compiler ?

What makes a compiler "right"?